# How to find the value of a known attribute and token using the xml golang std. lib

Tags: xml, go

I'm parsing the body of an http request that is set up in like this:

```
<something>
...
<inner_something> 
...
<foo bar='VALUE_I_WANT'>
... 
</FOO >
...
</inner_something>
...
</something>
```

What is an idiomatic approach to finding `VALUE_I_WANT`? Can I loop though the tokens using a decoder? How can check that a token is foo and get the attribute bar? (those names are constant). Is that the only way using the std lib? No way to look up tokens directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `encoding/xml` package to parse your data. For example, define types representing your XML data:

```
type Something struct {
    InnerSomething struct {
        Foo struct {
            Bar string `xml:"bar,attr"`
        } `xml:"foo"`
    } `xml:"inner_something"`
} 

type Result struct {
    Something `xml:"something"`
}
```

Then parse the data:

```
func main() {
    data := `
<something>
    <inner_something>
        <foo bar='VALUE_I_WANT'>test
        </foo >
    </inner_something>
</something>`
    v := Result{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("bar: %q", v.Something.InnerSomething.Foo.Bar)
}
```

See https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/.

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/Mv2mZLNVoUc) is a working sample in the Go Playground.

Comment: Well I guess that'll work. Lot of set up though. Thanks!